# How to edit or add video metadata of “rotation” in ts?

Tags: ffmpeg

The source video file is flv format, and I want to remux it to ts format. I want to rotate the ts file by anticlockwise 90 degress, if so, I must decode and recode the file to use avfilter, and the process cost a lot. I want to know whether I can add metadata to the object ts file, and the player can rotate the ts file by the metadata when playing.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not such standard feature for TS. You can put custom metadata in the stream, but you must also modify the player to read that metadata and rotate on render.

Comment: AVFormatContext and AVStream both have metadata field. Which structure metadata should I modify? And what metadata should I add?